# grpc.pb.h *cc files include only namespaces without code

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm trying to generate grpc code from protobuf files.

Generate "empty" grpc.pb* files, which include only dependencies and namespaces.

```
sudo protoc -I contracts --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=_deps/grpc-build/grpc_cpp_plugin contracts/events.proto
```

Output of that command looks like normally, files with generated code.

```
sudo protoc -I contracts --cpp_out=. contracts/events.proto
```

Can some one help me to figure out that is the problem?

events.pb.cc

```
// Generated by the gRPC C++ plugin.
// If you make any local change, they will be lost.
// source: events.proto

#include "events.pb.h"
#include "events.grpc.pb.h"

#include <functional>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_unary_call.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/channel_interface.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_unary_call.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_callback.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/message_allocator.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/method_handler.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_service_method.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_callback.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_callback_handlers.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_context.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/service_type.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/sync_stream.h>
namespace proto {
namespace tradeapi {
namespace v1 {

}  // namespace proto
}  // namespace tradeapi
}  // namespace v1
```

protoc command does not provide any warnings or errors messages

events.proto includes some dependencies:

```
import "common.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```